# mvc partial view js file not working debug

Tags: javascript, debugging

hello If I use inside js file view
javascript debug not working

Person.js

```
function LoadPersons() {

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Person/GetPersons/',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 
        async: false,
        success: function (result) {

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            DynamicAlertifyFunction('error', 'GetCrew');
        }
    });

}
Person.cshtml 
    <script src="~/scripts/Person.js"></script>



  <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            LoadPersons(); 
        });
    </script
```

but If I use inside js file _Layout debug is working why ?

```
Person.cshtml 
@*  <script src="~/scripts/Person.js"></script>*@

_Layout.cshtml 
    <script src="~/scripts/Person.js"></script>
```

thank you

Comment: user GetPersons() instead of GerPersons() <button  href="#" onclick="GerPersons();"></button>

Comment: GetPersons() function is working only debug not working

Comment: where is debugger in file??? and also you cannot get any value in return

Comment: Inside javascript view means?

Comment: is there any errors are log in browser console?

Comment: PersonLoads() is working only js File on debugging does not work

Comment: make sure that there is not issue of jquery. might be jquery order is not correct. put your jquery.js before person.js

Comment: actually I am not getting what you want to explain but I think you have problem with "return returnData" actually you cannot return like this you have to call callback function.

Answer (score 0):

Just to check, are you referencing the jquery file before or after you call Person.js? If you're implementing your partial view, and then calling jquery at the bottom of the _layout page, then you won't instantiate $.ajax in Person.cshtml.

Also, again, not too sure if you're doing this or not, but bear in mind that sections do not work in partial views, so make sure that you aren't including the script tag within a @section scripts {} in Person.cshtml.